# What is the difference between these two for loops in C?

Tags: c++, c

```
int i;
for(i = n; i --> 0;)
```

and

```
for(i = n; i > 0; --i)
```

They are producing different results.

Comment: the first one is equivalent to `for(i = n; i> 1; i--)`

Comment: `size_t i = 42; while (i --> 0) {}`, why not...

Comment: `for(i = n; i> 1; i--)` is giving a different result than first or second loop.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie: No one knows when the decrement is perfomed: it can be done before or after. It does not matter. What matters is that post-increment evaluates to tyhe *original* value of `i`.

Answer (score 4):

As for the first one, `i` is decremented *before* the loop body is executed. The second one decrements `i` *after* the loop body is executed.

Comment: I find your answer incomplete as it does not discuss the behaviour (value) of `i` in the comparisson.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie well, the value of i in the comparison is the same for both cases. The postfix decrement means the COMPARISON is with the value before decrementing - but because the decrement is now at the head of the loop, the value of `i` in the loop is different.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The comparison is the same, both loops iterate _n_ times with the same values. The only difference is the value of `i` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is the step in which `i` is actually decremented, which affects the values of `i` seen *inside* the loop body.

The second traditional version decrements `i` after the loop body is executed, and before the condition is checked again. Thus `i` reaches 0 after the loop body is executed for `i == 1`. The condition is checked again and after the loop `i` is 0.

The first version decrements `i` before the loop body is executed, as part of the condition being checked. Here the loop body runs the first time with `i == n - 1` and the last time with `i == 0`. Then `i` is decremented and its previous value compared against `0`. The loop exits and `i` is -1 after it.

In the traditional version, the loop body always sees the same value against which the conditional part was checked.

Comment: ..so in the loop, `i` is the first time `n-1` and `i` is in the last iteration `0`. And after the loop, `i` is `-1`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie - Yeah, good point. Added the last value of `i` for both versions.